# SVN client for Fedora 17 and nautilus

Tags: bash, svn, fedora, nautilus

I'm Fedora 17 linux user and I've searched a good alternative to RabbitVCS for SVN eg.
15.0.5 version witch it's not very stable for my FC17 box. My last choice is nautilus-action-scrips.

Can sombody help me with some choises for Gnome 3 ?

Comment: By client for nautilus you mean a client that allows integration into the context menu? If no, you can use any Java-based SVN client, they work everywhere.

Comment: What problem are you having with RabbitVCS? If you think the problems you're having might be solved by a new version (and they might; there have been 9 months of development since the last stable release), you can install the development version: `sudo yum install python-pip && sudo pip install svn+http://rabbitvcs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/#egg=rabbitvcs`

Comment: I've sticked now on java version using my Eclipse Juno with Subclipse plugin and SVNKit. It is much faster than any linux native SVN client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RapidSVN

```
sudo yum install rapidsvn
```

Alternatively you can download the source from [here](http://www.rapidsvn.org/download/release/0.12.1/rapidsvn-0.12.1.tar.gz) and build yourself